# Guidelines to quickly parse a simple language

Tags: c++, parsing, c++11

Somethings I find my self needing to parse some kind of simple language. A language more expressive than *regular expressions*, yet is something so small that does not worth the effort of using something so powerful as bison.

I end up doing a *ad-hoc* parser using unit tests to guarantee it's correctness. I create a function that extracts a single token, and another function that will keep extracting tokens and through a few loops and a lot of ifs will parse the language. But, it is not the right way to parse a language, and if someone saw the code would not understand that it was meant to do.

I was looking for some better solutions to quickly parse small languages. Some library, or some kind of technique to solve this problem.

Comment: What's wrong with bison? If you've got a simple language, the bison parser is simple, too.

Comment: You could have a look at [Boost.Spirit](http://boost-spirit.com/home/). ([Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/index.html))

Comment: @rici Actually, I love bison. But it is another dependency that I am adding to my project. But maybe I could add the generated files on version control? I dont know...

Comment: @AndréPuel, I believe that is a common way to distribute code; you can distribute both the bison source and the generated files. If you avoid putting library code in the `.y` file, you will probably find that changes are uncommon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a perfectly fine way to parse a language. Keep the tokenization and parsing portions separated, with maybe an enum or two to hold the different types of tokens. I don't see why such an approach would lead to unclean code, especially for fairly simple languages.

Other than that, bison should work fine and its not much of intellectual overhead to use it.